# input box no longer updating colors to respective boxes

Tags: javascript, html, dom, colors

Working on a color palette picker for helping myself make website palettes, im encountering an issue where the square color isn't being updated when you type a color and press the "Update" button. I had it editable on the top of each card where you could input colors and push the paint bucket/update button beside the input box and it would fill the color out into he card but somehow but i broke that part and it isnt populating the squares with the new color.  any help is appreciated. The link the [full codepen](https://codepen.io/Oliver-Kirsch/pen/mdadLxd) is here if you want to be able to easily pull up what im talking about.

heres the relevvant html

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css">

    <h1>Color Palette Picker</h1>
    <div id="container">
      <div class="square">

        <div class="color-info">
          <span class="color-code" contenteditable>#3498db</span> <button class="change-color-button" style="border 1px;"><i class="fas fa-fill"></i></button><br><br><br><br><br><br><button class="lock-button"><i class="fas fa-unlock"></i></button>
        </div>
      </div>
```

heres the relevant js i think and also lookat the codepen if you cant find an issue here

```
    squares.forEach((square) => {
      // ... Your Existing Code ...

      const changeColorButton = square.querySelector(".change-color-button");

      // ... Your Existing Code ...
    
     changeColorButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
        const newColor = colorInput.value;
        updateSquareColor(square, newColor);
      });
    });

    function updateSquareColor(square, newColor) {
     square.style.backgroundColor = newColor;
     square.querySelector(".color-code").textContent = newColor;
   }

      const changeColorButton = square.querySelector(".change-color-button");
      const colorInput = square.querySelector(".color-input");

      changeColorButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
        const newColor = colorInput.value;
        updateSquareColor(square, newColor);
      });
    });
```

what i tried so far among other things:

Verified for listeners: made sure the listeners were connected in the html

Verified the Input Field: We checked if you had an input field for color input (color-input) associated with each square. Without this input field, the color wouldn't update properly.

Updated JavaScript: We advised modifying the JavaScript code to add an event listener to each square's change-color-button. This listener would retrieve the color input value when the button is clicked and use the updateSquareColor function to update the square's color.

Comment: Looking at your pen, you add an event listener to `changeContentButton` but that variable is not defined anywhere.

Comment: @ChrisBarr Thank you so much! I have only been coding a week and this helped me a lot. You are correct turns out I accidentally deleted the function, definition and call of the function when my cats stepped n my keyboard and i spammed ctrl + z. So again thank you

Comment: Lol, I love that it's your cat to blame for this one!  I'm going to recommend you use ESLint to catch simple issues like this.  You can install it in your project with NPM, or you can copy/paste your single file of code onto their playground: https://eslint.org/

Comment: @ChrisBarr i have it on vs code installed actually didn't think to use it, i will remember next time. and not the cats more so my reaction to the cats caused this by accidentally deleting the code.  i have two kittens who love my desk, they enjoy pausing my movies and stepping on my keyboard. Unrelated completely but i saw youre a UI/front end dev, what other plugins do you recommend off the bat for my ease of use since that's where id like to head towards.

Comment: Keep in mind that the ESLint plugin doesn't really do anything by itself. You need to install eslint into your project via NPM and the plugin uses that information to underline code issues you defined. The "Code spell checker" is a great one to find all kinds of typos in your text and variable names,  "Live Server" makes coding simple stuff much easier since it will auto-refresh your browser whenever you save a files.